# not able to understand the role of getchar and putchar here

Tags: c, getchar, putchar

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int c;
    c = getchar();
    while (c != EOF) {
         putchar(c);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

when I compile and give input ABC and then press enter, the never ending loop starts like AAAAAAAAA....

And now look at this code below

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int c;
    c = getchar();
    while (c != EOF) {
         putchar(c);
         c = getchar ();   // added this single line 
    }
    return 0;
}
```

In this program, when I input ABC, the output is ABC.
Can anyone please explain why it is not showing just a single A as output?

Comment: Of course. You press [Enter] which generates an `'\n'` which is read with `getchar()` into `c` and you then test `while (c != EOF)` (forever). Adding the additional line attempts an additional input stopping the infinite loop (you could press `ctrl+d`, or `ctrl+z` - on windows to generate a manual `EOF` -- but see [CTRL+Z does not generate EOF in Windows 10](http://proc-x.com/2017/06/ctrlz-does-not-generate-eof-in-windows-10/))

Comment: Resd this article: https://en.m.wikibooks.org/wiki/C_Programming/stdio.h/getchar

Comment: Why do you expect the second example to print a single `A` only?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at the below code you mentioned

```
int main(void){
        int c;
        c = getchar();
        while (c != EOF) {
                putchar(c);

        }
        return 0;
}
```

When `c = getchar();` executes & if you provided input as `ABC` at **runtime** & press `ENTER(\n)`, that time `c` holds  **first** character `A`.
Next come to loop, your condition is `c!=EOF` i.e `A!=EOF` which always true & it will print `A` infinitely because you are not asking second time input so `c` holds `A`.

correct version of above code is

```
int main(void){
        int c;
        while ( (c = getchar())!=EOF) { /* to stop press ctrl+d */
                putchar(c);
        }
        return 0;
}
```

**case 2 :-** Now looks at second code

```
int main(void){
        int c;
        c = getchar(); 
        while (c != EOF) { /*condition is true */
                putchar(c);  
                c = getchar ();/*After printing ABC, it will wait for second input like DEF, unlike case-1  */ 
        }
        return 0;
}
```

*Can anyone please explain why it is not showing just a single A as output ?* Why it should prints only `A`, it prints whatever input you given like `ABC` & so on. Just note that `getchar()` works with buffered input i.e when you press `ENTER` `getchar()` will read upto that & when there is nothing left to read `getchar()` returns `EOF`.